# How can I use SignalR to establish communication between the users of a AD group?

Tags: .net, active-directory, signalr

I want to create an application that allows communication between a certain group of people in the company. Assuming that this group is defined in AD already somehow, would it be possible to seamlessly integrate SignalR with the AD group, so that each message is broadcast to the whole group?

The application will most likely be a WPF or Windows Forms client with a notification bar. There will be a notification icon that will change color depending on if any user in the group is in a meeting or a call. The purpose is to warn everyone else in the room about it so that they try to keep silent.

Having SignalR communicate between these people would allow me to not have to worry about having a server application to do it. It would be kind of a P2P communication. I would need to use the Active Directory API I think to retrieve the group, and then link SignalR to it somehow.

Is that at all possible or am I going the wrong way with this approach?

Comment: Are you familiar with working with Active Directory in C#? Have a look [at this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/1/1/active-directory.aspx).

Comment: If you can get the users from AD, then you can use the AD credentials to authenticate in your application. From this point on,  it is just a chat app. Hope this helps

Comment: @Matei_Radu I'm not very familiar with the .Net AD API, but I did some tests now and I think I can extract what I need, which is the room identifier. Then the problem becomes on how to communicate with SignalR using that information. I thought about creating a group in SignalR with the room identifier as the name, so when new clients open the application, they will be automatically connected to their group. But SignalR is a client-server API, so maybe I'll have to self host it on each client to make this work? Any examples of that you could provide?

Comment: Did you make any improvements in this  application?

Answer (score 0):

If you can create a WPF app with users logging in using the domain account (hence the AD account), then adding SignalR to this kind of application is rather a simple task.

Take a [look at this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/804770/Implementing-SignalR-in-Desktop-Applications) for how to setup SignalR for a WPF application.

Hope this helps! Best of luck!